# How do I perfect forward as generically as possible?

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

I have this example:

```
template<class ValueType>
class MyTemplateClass
{
public:
    MyTemplateClass(ValueType&& Value) : MyMemberVar{ std::forward<ValueType>(Value) } {}
    
private:
    ValueType MyMemberVar;
};

int main()
{
    int x{ 5 };
    MyTemplateClass<int> Instance{ x };
    
    return 0;
}
```

This code does not compile, with: `error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'int&&' to lvalue of type 'int'`.

I understand the error. A fix would be to give it an rvalue like so:

```
MyTemplateClass<int> Instance{ 5 };
```

But this isn't very usable. I could also give it a more specific type:

```
MyTemplateClass<const int&> Instance{ x };
```

But I feel like this could be better. For instance, std::vector can do:

```
int x = 5;
std::vector<int>{ x, x, x };
```

This works just fine... how does std::vector accomplish this? Is there something wrong with my code?

Thank you.

Comment: I think the problem is that `ValueType` is fixed once the class template is deduced.  You need the constructor to be a function template with a (separate) parameter that can vary independent of the class parameter.  You are allowed to have a function template nested within a class template, and I believe that is the only way to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there something wrong with my code?

Yes.

---

The constructor you have written:

```cpp
MyTemplateClass(ValueType&& Value);
```

`Value` is not a forwarding reference here, it is just an rvalue reference. To make it a forwarding reference, the type of `Value` must be a template parameter of this particular function:

```cpp
template<typename T>
MyTemplateClass(T&& Value) : MyMemberVar{ std::forward<T>(Value) } {}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E9q819rMY)